# why curl timeout when get from url?

Tags: php, curl

why would cURL in PHP return timeout message when get HTML from web page?

Here is the PHP code.

```html
function getFromUrl( $url )
{
  $curl = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($curl);

  if (curl_errno($curl))
  {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curl) . '<br>' ;
  }

  curl_close($curl);

  return $result ;
}
```

I get the expected results when I run the function with www.google.com as the URL.

```js
  $url = 'http://www.google.com' ;
  $result = getFromUrl($url) ;
```

But, when I pass in the URL of web page on a 2nd web server, I get a timeout response. The URL exists when I paste it into a browser. Why the timeout message?

```js
$url = "http://xxx.54.20.170:10080/accounting/tester/hello.html" ;
echo $url . '<br>' ;
$rv = getFromUrl( $url ) ;
echo  $rv . '<br>' ;
```

here is the cURL error message:

Error:Failed to connect to xxx.54.20.170 port 10080: Connection timed out

I am looking to transfer data from one web server to another.

thanks,

Comment: What's the result of running `curl http://xxx.54.20.170:10080/accounting/tester/hello.html` in terminal?

Comment: @meysam add -v to that, `curl -v http://xxx.54.20.170:10080/accounting/tester/hello.html`

Comment: I ran curl from the command line and it worked. Returned the html of the page.  It only fails when I run from PHP code on a shared hosting site and the target is a port that is forwarded from the router in my office. I forward port 10080 to a web server behind the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

For PHP,

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400); //timeout in seconds
```

From terminal first check if curl is working using below extra options.

> --connect-timeout 
>       Maximum  time  in  seconds  that you allow the connection to the
>       server to take.  This only limits  the  connection  phase,  once
>       curl has connected this option is of no more use.  Since 7.32.0,
>       this option accepts decimal values, but the actual timeout  will
>       decrease in accuracy as the specified timeout increases in deci‐
>       mal precision. See also the -m, --max-time option.
>
> ```
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
> ```

and

> -m, --max-time 
>       Maximum  time  in  seconds that you allow the whole operation to
>       take.  This is useful for preventing your batch jobs from  hang‐
>       ing  for  hours due to slow networks or links going down.  Since
>       7.32.0, this option accepts decimal values, but the actual time‐
>       out will decrease in accuracy as the specified timeout increases
>       in decimal precision.  See also the --connect-timeout option.
>
> ```
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.
> ```

Try to use them to increase timeout time.

There are many reasons for curl not working. Some of them can be,
1) Response time is slow.
2) Few site has check on few header parameters to respond to request. These parameters include User-Agent, Referer, etc to make sure it is coming from valid source and not through bots.

Comment: thanks for this.  In my case, the shared hosting site my PHP code was running on blocks traffic to port 10080.